# Kubelet image GC for docker "Data Space Total" instead of disk space

Tags: docker, garbage-collection, kubernetes, docker-image

Docker 1.10.2

Kubernetes 1.1.7

I start docker with parameter

```
--graph=/mydisk/mypath/
```

And start Kubelet with parameters

```
--docker-root=/mydisk/mypath/ --image-gc-high-threshold=80 --images-gc-low-threshold=60
```

docker info shows me Data Space Total: 107.4 GB. And mydisk is 1.2T.
With a long time running, the total size of pulled docker images reaches 107.4GB. Then docker daemon crashes.
I do not want to set

```
--storage-opt dm.loopdatasize=1.2T
```

for docker. So what can I do to make Kubelet image GC for docker "Data Space Total" instead of disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes v1.2+ is expected to support garbage collection of docker images with device mapper docker storage driver.